# How many algebras of subsets of $X$ contain exactly four elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let X be a set with five elements. How many algebras of subsets of X contain
exactly four subsets?

Well $\emptyset, X$ must be in any algebra of subsets of $X$ so that means we have to find two more elements.

$A$ in the algebra of subsets $\implies$ $A^C$ is in the algebra.

And $A, B$ in the algebra $\implies$ A $\bigcup B$ is in the algebra.

So this means that the remaining two elements of the algebra must have two and three elements.

So I count $5 \choose 2$ ways we can make that happen.

Is that correct?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you asking how many algebras have four elements; or how many algebras have a four elements set?

Answer (score 2):

Other than the $\binom{5}{2}$ algebras you have, there are also ones where the remaining $2$ sets have $1$ and $4$ members respectively. There are $\binom{5}{1}$ ways to choose those.

So the total number is: $\binom{5}{2} + \binom{5}{1} = 15$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\dfrac{2^5-2}{2}=15$. Because if $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset,X,A,B\}$ is a such algebra then $B=A^c$, that is $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset, X,A,A^c \}$ this algebra depend only of $A$ and $A^c$.

Comment: I am missed here five=$4$? thinks.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a subset with four elements, then there are $\frac{2^5-2}{2}=15$   algebras of subsets of $X$ which  contain exactly four subsets.